# how to add factor to y-axis and redraw when range in navigator changes

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a stock performance chart, very similar to this chart:

https://www.orbis.com/bm/private-client/funds/global-equity

The idea is that the y-axis always starts at 10,000 and moves from there. When the navigator range changes, the top area is redrawn by applying a factor to all the data points.  And even though the chart changes, the navigator area does not change.

Any ideas on how to do this with highstock?

Comment: Hi @somakani, Could you describe more precisely what you want to achieve? However, you can catch `afterSetExtremes` and adapt y-axis labels according to your needs. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v0hepd72/

Comment: based on your sample (by the way thanks), if I change the data a little to percents, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jtcydnkq/ what I would like to do is if I move the navigator to focus from the middle to the right, (1) the navigator line stays the same as before, and (2) the top chart is redrawn with the left most value as 100. If the center falls on the value 100.35 from my list, I would divide everything to the right by 100.35 and draw: 100,100.95,100.57,99.28,97.56,99.95,91.34,94.28,95.03,94.56,95.1,94.92

Comment: Hi @somakani, Thanks for the explanation! I still don't understand the part about dividing data to the right, but I was able to create this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gzpk43Ld/ which I hope is one step forward.

Comment: @ppotaczek: you're awesome! that was it.  Made a slight change to your fiddle.  Here is the change: http://jsfiddle.net/kct7yw20/   the key was the adaptToUpdatedData for the navigator!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ppotaczek for the answer.  It was simpler than I was trying to make it.  Simplicity is genius.
This is the solution

```
const baseData = [100.00, 99.78, 96.50, 96.61, 97.57, 96.02, 96.42, 99.17, 100.35, 101.30, 100.92, 99.63, 97.90, 100.30, 91.66, 94.61, 95.36, 94.89, 95.43, 95.25, 96.70, 93.58, 92.53];

[100, 100.95, 100.57, 99.28, 97.56, 99.95, 91.34, 94.28, 95.03, 94.56, 95.1, 94.92]

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  series: [{
    data: baseData.slice()
  }],
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
        const min = e.min;
        const max = e.max;

        const visibleData = baseData.filter(
          (dataEl, index) => index > min && index <= max + 1
        );
                factor = 100.00/visibleData[0];
        const finalData = [];

        visibleData.forEach((dataEl, index) => {
          finalData.push([min + index, dataEl*factor]);
        });

        this.series[0].setData(finalData);
      }
    },
    minRange: 1
  },
  navigator: {
    adaptToUpdatedData: false
  }
});
```